# Force from screw on the clamp

Tags: machine-design, computer-aided-design, force-measurement

[image: Design of the clamp, I have highlighted the screw]

I want to find out the force the screw (M5 , 12mm long) exerts on the clamp so it can hold the cylinder as shown in the image. I want to know whether the clamp can displace enough to hold the cylider tight. The tolerance is 200 microns between the clamp and the cylinder inside.

Comment: what does hold the cylinder entail? usually going against gravity and any other forces.  what does displacing entail? likely deformation without breaking- makes a difference whether it is rubber or steel and geometry matters.  Could you provide more info along those lines?  materials of clamp, bolt, cylinder, geometry of clamp, and forces on cylinder?

Comment: Is the cylinder rotated? in a direction to close or open the clamp?

Comment: Unless clamping is very light, I'm guessing forces will depend mostly on elasticity of either the clamp and the cylinder being held, with the clamp tending to be strong enough to firmly impose the adjusted inside diameter resulting from the adjustment screw that controls it.

Comment: @Abel Sorry I should have added that info : so the cylinder is a 2.5 Kg sensor and the clamp needs to hold it against gravitational force. The clamp itself is will be attached to the table on the side. The clamp material is aluminium. Screw is mild steel . To calculate how much the clamp deforms due to axial force from the screw on solidworks simulation I need to know the force from the screw on the clamp

Answer (score 1):

Acceptable clamp load is 75% of the proof load of the bolt. Proof load is the maximum tensile stress on the bolt in the elastic range.

here is a partial table of Metric Bolt proof loads.

[Source](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/metric-bolts-minimum-ultimate-tensile-proof-loads-d_2026.html)

'

[image: proof load]